# Angular ng-disabled checking multiple values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check multiple values in `ng-disabled`.

I am trying

```
ng-disabled = "{{ (id === po.adm_sid) ||  (sid === po.opm_sid) }}"
```

which doesn't work. It works when I check a single value. I also tried:

```
ng-disabled = "{{ id === (po.adm_sid ||  po.opm_sid) }}"
```

Comment: Stupid question (mine). Are you sure that at least one of the two tests case are true? :)

Comment: Do You want to disable element when _both_ conditions are True, or at least one of them?

Comment: take out {{}}. ngDsabled attribute evaluates expressions. So no need of {{}}. More details here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: I want to check if id is equal to atleast one of them! @anirudh didn't work even without a {{ }}

Comment: Is it possible to create a plinkr or something....As per my understanding data-ng-disabled="id===po.adm_sid || id === po.opm_sid" should work.....It might seem silly but i think there is a typo in your question...in the first scenario you are checking sid and in second just the id....

Answer (score 3):

I would make a helper function and not have multiple checks in the html. Something like:

```
ng-disabled = "isDisabled()" 

$scope.isDisabled = function(){
   return (id === po.adm_sid) || (sid === po.opm_sid);
}
```

I usually have better luck with this kind of set up for multiple value checking in the html

Comment: Then you can test the function too!  Hooray for unit tests!